# Qiskit BasicAer simulator options

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I usually use Qiskit "Aer" to simulate quantum circuit with several methods such as `statevector`, `density_matrix`, `stabilizer`, `extended_stabilizer`, and `matrix_product_state`. Recenlty I came across another simulator called "BasicAer" and I wonder if the qiskit BasicAer supports above methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any provider, you can check the backends with `backends()`:

```
from qiskit import BasicAer
BasicAer.backends()
```

```
[<QasmSimulatorPy('qasm_simulator') from BasicAer()>,
 <StatevectorSimulatorPy('statevector_simulator') from BasicAer()>,
 <UnitarySimulatorPy('unitary_simulator') from BasicAer()>]
```

Check the doc for each of them:

```
for backend in BasicAer.backends():
    print("%s: %s" % (backend.name(), backend.__doc__))
```

```
qasm_simulator: Python implementation of a qasm simulator.
statevector_simulator: Python statevector simulator.
unitary_simulator: Python implementation of a unitary simulator.
```